# How to authenticate with credentails while cloning a Git repository

Tags: git, bash

I am using the below GIT bash commands to download the file from GIT remote repository.Some of my GIT repositories can be accessed without SSO authentication and some of them are authenticated with SSO.My git bash command works only with the repositories where SSO authentication is not needed.

I would like to know how can i supply my SSO credentials to the below command.

```
   git init
   git config --global http.sslVerify false
   git pull https://github-cloudcreations.orange.cloud.corp.myDomain.com/DoaminCloud/myrepo.git DEVELOPMENT
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: you should not post the URL of your GIT repo like that, just for safety reasons.

Now if I understand your question correctly, you don't want to have to authenticate (type in your username and password) whenever you push or pull from your git repo.

The easiest way around having to authenticate every time is to use git over ssh and not http.

Basically, import your git repo with

```
git checkout git@github-cloudcreations.orange.cloud.corp.myDomain.com/DoaminCloud/myrepo.git
```

or if you already have your repo in http, you can just update the remote URL with the command

```
git remote set-url origin git@github-cloudcreations.orange.cloud.corp.myDomain.com/DoaminCloud/myrepo.git
```

Comment: Use git over ssh, and add your client's public key to known hosts on the remote server(ssh-copy-id), so that ssh won't prompt for password.

Comment: I have to authenticate with my SSO credentials first to access a git repository.I just want to know how to authenticate with my credentials while trying to access git from git bash.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an https url (and not an ssh one), you can use:

```
git ls-remote https://....
```

That will ask for your credentials.

Make sure to setup first a **[credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)** which will cache those username/password for you.

Then you can git clone/pull without having to enter them again.